# BeautifulSoup's Python 3 compatibility

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, porting

Does BeautifulSoup work with Python 3?

If not, how soon will there be a port? Will there be a port at all?

Google doesn't turn up anything to me (Maybe it's 'coz I'm looking for the wrong thing?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About two months after I asked this question, a port has been released:

http://groups.google.com/group/beautifulsoup/browse_thread/thread/f24882cc17a0625e

It'll bet BS working, but that's about it. Not yet tried it though.

Answer (score 20):

Beautiful Soup **4.x** [officially supports Python 3.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/beautifulsoup/VpNNflJ1rPI/sum07jmEwvgJ)

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: When I tried to use it, it gave me an error saying I was using the python 2 .x version on python 3.x

Answer (score 3):

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ says:

> Download Beautiful Soup
>
> If you're using Python 2.3 through
>   2.6, the 3.0 series is the best choice. The most recent release in the
>   3.0 series is 3.0.8, released November 30, 2009.
>
> If you're using Python 3.0, you must
>   use the 3.1 series. Beautiful Soup
>   version 3.1.0.1 was released January
>   6, 2009. You can use the 3.1 series
>   with earlier versions of Python, but
>   you might run into the problems
>   described here.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [release candidate for Python 3.0](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/) available, so you can always test BeautifulSoup's compatibility yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the answer is "No".  According to [Python.org](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/):

> Python 3000 (a.k.a. "Py3k", and
>   released as Python 3.0) is a new
>   version of the language that is
>   incompatible with the 2.x line of
>   releases. The language is mostly the
>   same, but many details, especially how
>   built-in objects like dictionaries and
>   strings work, have changed
>   considerably, and a lot of deprecated
>   features have finally been removed.
>   Also, the standard library has been
>   reorganized in a few prominent places.

A better place for this particular question might be the [BeautifulSoup forum](http://groups.google.com/group/beautifulsoup).

Answer (score 0):

yes,beautiful soup work in python 3,

Linux

```
apt-get install python3-bs4
```

Windows

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

For more information see https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup